# How to fill cell with data from a separate worksheet in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to match 2 columns in two separate worksheets and then fill data from worksheet 2 in worksheet 1.

I need to match Column A(Worksheet 2) to Column D(Worksheet 1). Once Matched I need to fill Column F(Worksheet 1) with the data from Column B(Worksheet 2). Once data is populated I would also like to change the color of Column F(Worksheet 1) based on the data that is present. [Worksheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpu8G.png)
[Worksheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNnAL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in F2 On Sheet 1, update the sheet name `Sheet2` to whatever your second sheet is named, then copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP($D2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Then you can apply conditional formatting to Column F on Sheet 1.

If you might have values in Sheet 1 that aren't in Sheet 2, this will handle the error:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"Not Found!")
```

**[Updated for additional question about spanning accross workbooks]**

For another open workbook, use the following and replace `[Book2]` with the path of the second workbook or the name of an open workbook:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2,[Book2]Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"Not Found!")
```

Also note, Excel will automatically build all of the references if you select them manually while building the formula in the formula bar: [Excel Formulas Overview on MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-formulas-in-excel-ecfdc708-9162-49e8-b993-c311f47ca173)

Comment: Thanks! I was sure it would be a vlookup but I am still trying to learn the ropes!

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do it across two separate workbooks? Currently I am copy/paste the worksheet 2 from a different workbook.

Comment: yes, you have to provide the path `=VLOOKUP($D2,[C:\...\Book2.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)` where "C:\...\" is the actual path of your workbook. This will create a link that has to be updated, usually when the workbook is opened. And the user needs to have access to that path. If you are configuring this from a workbook that is already open, then `=VLOOKUP($D2,[Book2]Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE)` where `Book2` is the name of the second workbook, will work; it will figure out the rest of the path (if it is a saved workbook.)

Comment: One more request on top of returning the value. I would I add on top of the formula to say change the return value from "Lend" to "L". I am sure there is a few IF statements involved but don't know if that is the best was to go. There are 6 values I will need to do this for.

Comment: There are a few ways you could do that, but if you are only looking to change "Lend" then `=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2,[Book2]Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"Not Found!"),"Lend","L")`

Comment: Essentially I have 6 different strings that I will only need to return the first character of. Hopefully that clarification makes it easier.

Comment: Lend = L; Collect = C ; Protect = P; Efficiency = E; Compliance/Risk/Legal = CRL; Other = O

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed to provide you with an exact code but here is a good start

'Assuming there are 10 rows in each worksheet

```
dim i as integer
dim j as integer

for i = 1 to 10
    for j = 1 to 10 
        if sheet1.cells(i,4).value = sheet2.cells(j,1).value then
            sheet1.cells(i,6).value = sheet1.cells(j,2).value
            sheet1.cells(i,6).interior.color = vbyellow
        end if
    next j
next i
```

the color can also be controlled with the rgb function, simply replace the vbyellow in the above code:

For example rgb(255,204,255) will be a light pink